# Is there a C# equivalent of java's AbstractList?

Tags: c#, java, .net, list, collections

Java `AbstractList` class is very convenient when you need to implement the `List` interface whithout having to code everything from scratch.

Now, in C#, I need to implement a view on a part of my datamodel that would implement `IList`.

Is there an abstract class in .Net that I could inherit, in the same way that I would extend `AbstractList` if it was in Java ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`.

Comment: don't forget to flag as "answer"

Comment: @NaNNy I know but there's a minimum delay to give a chance to other ppl to provide a better answer.